# Glyphs rendering support on Virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, glyph

Do Glyph Libraries support and render on Virtual machine, Using Oracle Virtual Box and when creating glyph image, virtual box is getting rebooted.

Comment: When you ask the question here then you have to provide some snippets of your code. So can others will get idea and give the solution.

Comment: Hi Harsha, these are the guidelines you should follow before asking your question on stack overflow community - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask